# What are preserved properties in NAnt?

Tags: nant

What are preserved properties in NAnt?
Please help.

Comment: Please provide some more details. What is the context?

Comment: Yes Chairman,
While writing NAnt script .build file, we define properties using <property name="" value="" ... > tag.
I don't know if there are any preserved value for the 'name'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list of the built-in properties: http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/fundamentals/properties.html#built-in-properties